# If I buy a bulk product and resell in small packages, do I need to label them?

Tags: united-states, commerce

If I buy a bulk product (several pounds) and resell it in 0.5 ounce packages (this is typically how it is sold, so this would be like a “group buy” except I am fronting the cost)

Do I need to label the small packages with any text from the original package? e.g. the logo, place it was manufactured, etc

This is in the United States but potentially selling to other countries. The product is styptic powder which is a non-prescription powder which is used to stop bleeding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where would you be doing this?  How tightly are pet health products regulated in that jurisdiction

Answer (score 2):

Probably.

There isn't a general rule to answer the more general question:

> If I buy a bulk product (several pounds) and resell it in 0.5 ounce
> packages (this is typically how it is sold, so this would be like a
> “group buy” except I am fronting the cost)
>
> Do I need to label the small packages with any text from the original
> package? e.g. the logo, place it was manufactured, etc.

It depends upon the nature of the product.

> The product is styptic powder which is a non-prescription powder which
> is used to stop bleeding

The Food and Drug Administration imposes some labeling requirements if something qualifies as a "food" or "drug" which depends, in part, upon how the product is marketed. In the example given, it is likely that FDA labeling requirements would apply.

There are also different laws that require labeling of certain kinds of products that are outside of FDA jurisdiction, such as many kinds of chemical products. So, even if it is not FDA regulated, it is likely to be regulated by some other agency.

Also, the Fair Trade Commission (FTC) imposes some federal regulation on marketing and labeling of goods that are not required to have specific labels but must comply with those regulations if they do. Generally speaking, these regulations prohibit certain kinds of deceptive marketing and labels.

Apart from labels, it is also likely that the business of distributing an OTC drug (if that is what it is) requires the business to be licensed by the FDA in addition to labeling requirements.

Interstate transit and postal shipping regulations typically require certain kinds of basic disclosures about the nature of packages that are shipped in order to keep dangerous items out of mailrooms and delivery vehicles. As one example, goods containing lithium-ion batteries must prominently disclose that content.

Given the history of anthrax poisoning crime attempts and cocaine trafficking, the U.S. Postal Service and other common carriers are generally going to require declarations of the nature of any product shipped that is a white powder.

And, of course, state regulatory regimes and deceptive trade practices acts might also apply.

> This is in the United States but potentially selling to other
> countries.

You must comply with the laws of every country to which a good is sold.

Comment: To expand on the 'nature of the product' point, if for example you buy large wooden boards, cut them to small pieces and then sell these you don't have to copy any labels or descriptions from the original product. It may be useful to provide some information but there is no legal requirement.

Comment: Food is also an area where labelling of ingredients is required